# can not working multiple database from my compose file

Tags: database, postgresql, docker, docker-compose, sequelize-typescript

here is my docker compose file

```
version: "3.8"
services:
  postgres:
    image: postgres
    volumes:
      - $HOME/db-data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_USER=postgres
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=admin123
      - POSTGRES_DB=cityevents
    ports:
      - 5432:5432
    container_name: postgres
    networks:
      - cityevents

  postgres-test:
    image: postgres
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_USER=postgres
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=admin123
      - POSTGRES_DB=postgres
    ports:
      - 5431:5432
    container_name: postgres-test
    networks:
      - cityevents

  api:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./Dockerfile
    image: api:v1
    ports:
      - 3000:3000
    volumes:
      - ./:/app
      - /app/node_modules
    container_name: api
    environment:
      - DB_HOST=${DB_HOST}
      - DB_NAME=${DB_NAME}
      - DB_USERNAME=${DB_USERNAME}
      - DB_PASSWORD=${DB_PASSWORD}
    entrypoint: [ "/bin/sh", "-c" ]
    command:
      - |
        npm i
        npm run migrate
        npm run dev
    networks:
      - cityevents
  api-test:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./Dockerfile
    image: api-test:v1
    ports:
      - 3001:3000
    volumes:
      - ./:/app
    container_name: test-api
    environment:
      - DB_TEST_HOST=${DB_TEST_HOST}
      - DB_TEST_NAME=${DB_TEST_NAME}
      - DB_USERNAME=${DB_USERNAME}
      - DB_PASSWORD=${DB_PASSWORD}
    entrypoint: [ "/bin/sh", "-c" ]
    command:
      - |
        npm i
        npm run migrate:undo:all
        npm run migrate
        npm run test
    networks:
      - cityevents

networks:
  cityevents:
```

.env

```
PORT=3000
database

DB_HOST=postgres DB_USERNAME=postgresDB_PASSWORD=admin123 DB_NAME=cityevents

# test-env

DB_TEST_NAME=postgres DB_TEST_HOST=postgres-test
```

config/config.js

```
const dotenv = require("dotenv");
dotenv.config();

module.exports = {
  development: {
    username: process.env.DB_USERNAME,
    password: process.env.DB_PASSWORD,
    database: process.env.DB_NAME,
    host: process.env.DB_HOST,
    dialect: "postgres",
    logging: true,
  },
  test: {
    username: process.env.DB_USERNAME,
    password: process.env.DB_PASSWORD,
    database: process.env.DB_TEST_NAME,
    host: process.env.DB_TEST_HOST,
    dialect: "postgres",
  },
  production: {
    username: "root",
    password: null,
    database: "database_production",
    host: "127.0.0.1",
    dialect: "postgres",
  },
};
```

I tried running container one by one from compose file and when I run `postgres` and `api service` its work perfectly but when I stop all running and check for `postgres-test` container, it is running
but when I try to connect with `pgadmin` it give me error like this

[can not connect pgAdmin with postgres-test service](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RIHrY.png)

it does happen when i run postgres-test where it work perfectly when run postgres

Thanks in Advance

i want to run all service with testing and development but can not connect with testing database

Comment: Unless I misunderstood your question, your `postgres-test` database is mapped to port 5431 on your host. The image you provided is you attempting to connect to port 5432, which is your `postgres`  service, not `postgres-test`.

Comment: thank you so much @AngelaLopez for your help and i found solution based on your ans 
In your case, if you are using 5433:5432 in the Docker Compose file, it means that port 5433 on the host machine is mapped to port 5432 inside the container. So, to connect to the PostgreSQL database running in the container, you would need to use 127.0.0.1:5433 or localhost:5433 as the connection address from your application running on the host machine.